# Entity Framework 4.1 Invalid object name

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am getting the following error in Entity Framework and cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing it.

Invalid object name 'dbo.User’

The actual table name in the database is called Users and I added it to my Entity Model by right clicking and selecting ‘Update Model From Database’ I have around six other models in my project all connecting to the same database which have pluralised table names and are updated in exactly the same way without any problems. It seems for some reason EF removes the ‘s’ from my table name when trying  to perform an update. As you can see from my code below I perform a selection before the update which works without problem.

I have also tried deleting the entity and recreating it unchecking the ‘Pluralize or singularize generated object names’. However the problem remains.

Any ideas would be appreciated on this one.

```
public void Update(User updatedUser)
{
    using (var context = CreateUserContext())
    {
        var entity = context.UserEntities
            .Where(u => u.UserId == updatedUser.UserId)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (entity != null)
        {
            entity.Name = updatedUser.Name;
            entity.Description = updatedUser.Description;
            entity.LastModifiedById = updatedUser.LastModifiedById;
            entity.IsDeleted = updatedUser.IsDeleted;

            context.UserEntities.ApplyCurrentValues(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you can select users leads me to believe the EF mapping is ok.

Check for a trigger on the table that is incorrectly using `dbo.User` as the table name.

As a side note, two things you can do to help diagnose a problem like this:

1. Try updating the row manually in SSMS.  This would tell you if the problem was with EF, or SQL Server (a trigger, constraint, etc.)
2. Use SQL Profiler to check the SQL statements that EF is sending to the database.

To check the SQL statements, you can also use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), although (at this time) you will need to [use the latest beta](http://www.linqpad.net/EntityFramework.aspx) to work with EF 4.1.

Comment: Excellent thanks very much. I used SQL Profiler and everything looked good with the update. I could then see the next action, forgot I had triggers on the tables to update the last modified time, derrr!!. Thanks again.

Comment: @Cragly, glad I was able to help, and I know it can be easy to forget about code in triggers, especially when you're focused on a different part of the application.